# How to access methods of mdi forms while convert string to form object in c# window application

Tags: c#, .net

I have one child form in c# .net .From that I am accessing MDI form like:

```
 Type t = Type.GetType("namespace" + "MdiFormName"); 
 Form c = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Form;
```

My MDI form is having one method named :

```
 public datatable CalluserRights()
```

Now I want to call `CalluserRights()`  method of MDI form from my child form.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
Type t = Type.GetType("namespace" + "MdiFormName"); 

MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("CalluserRights");

Form c = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Form;

//will call CalluserRights method and return datatable 
object datatable = method.Invoke(c, null);
```